# How to remove the default space coming in front of the gallery view in android using xml coding

Tags: android, android-gallery

There I am using the gallery view for the dynamic rendering of the images, but there is a default space coming in front and end of the gallery view. Is there is any way to remove the space?

here is my coding

```
                       <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@color/scrollimagebgcol"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp">


                        <Gallery
                            android:id="@+id/gallery1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:spacing="15dp"
                            />


                    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the padding in the parent `LinearLayout`, both `topPadding` and `bottomPadding`.

Comment: thnks, but when i remove the padding it remove the space coming at the top and bottom of the gallery. I want to remove the default space coming on right and left of the gallery. It means the space coming at the start and end of the gallery inside the horizontal scrolling

Comment: @anandaveluv can you include an image to show what you mean, there shouldn't be such spaces.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for a response. Please send me your mail id. I will share you a screen shot, because i cant share in it.

Comment: @anandaveluv you can add a screenshot in the question you posted, try using a computer to edit the question.

Comment: hi, i share the link for the gallery image  https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbnos0mndhan61p/gallery.png?dl=0

Comment: @anandaveluv I don't quite get what you are trying to do,the images in the gallery are centered when selected, hence the space from the right and left, its supposed to be like that. Maybe you want to disable the option of autoselecting in which case there are plenty of available answers.

Comment: k, thnks bro, Can you suggest me a way to remove the space coming at start and ending of all the images.

Comment: @anandaveluv in this case it's really simple, just put 0dp in the spacing attribute for the Gallery, if you do this the pictures will be closer together.